# DataGrid to DB - Using "Header Text" or "Design Name"

Tags: c#

I have been coding to:

- Read an XLS file
- Transform in a CSV (reason:  I will have to manipulate the file a lot)
- Create a Header (first line of the CSV)
- Use the CSV to populate a DataGrid
- Upload the Datagrid to DB

Problem:
- I always used the "Design Name" to upload in the DB. For example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DgridManuallyReceive.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                str = @"INSERT INTO TBL_MATRIX_CONTROL (A1
                                                        A2
                                                        A3
                                                        A4
                                                        A5
                                                        A5
                                                        A6
                                                        A7
                                                        A8
                                                        A9
                                                        A10
                                                        A11
                                                        A12
                                                        A13
                                                        ('" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A1"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A2"].Value + "', '" +
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A3"].Value + "', '" +
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A4"].Value + "', '" +
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A5"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A6"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A7"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A8"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A9"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A10"].Value + "', '" + 
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A11"].Value + "', '" +
                                                        DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A12"].Value + "', '" +
                                                        id_tbl_program
                                                        + "');";
```

The "DgridManuallyReceive.Rows[i].Cells["A1"].Value" refers to the "internal" name of the DataGridl.

Question:

- How do I discover and use these "internal" names if my DataGrid headers are being "automatic" created?

Part of the code that populates the DataGrid:

```
private void BindDataCSV(string filePath)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    if (lines.Length > 0)
    {

        // first line to create header
        string firstLine = lines[0];
        string[] headerLabels = firstLine.Split(',');
        //string[] headerLabels = new string[] { dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText };
        //string[] headerLabels = {"TestGroup" };




        foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerWord));
        }

        // for data

        for (int r = 1; r < lines.Length; r++)
        {
            string[] dataWords = lines[r].Split(',');
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            int columnIndex = 0;
            foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
            {

                dr[headerWord] = dataWords[columnIndex++];
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }


    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; }

}
```

The first line of my CSV will become the Header of my DataGrid. But I don't need these name, instead, I need the internal name of the field to upload to the DB.

[What do I mean with "Design name" and "Header name"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B98UpTa2n4XbWldTSWVPRWYzYlU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue using either name. I mean, in this case, I can use the "Header Name". The code also recognizes and upload to the DB.